# matplotlib matshow xtick labels on top and bottom

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a name co-occurrence matrix. This version works okay:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
names = ['Long Name ' + suffix for suffix in string.ascii_uppercase[:n]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n,n)),
                  columns=names, index=names)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

im = ax.matshow(df, interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(im)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n))
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(n))
ax.set_yticklabels(names)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("bottom")
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45,
         ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")

for (i,j), z in np.ndenumerate(df):
  if z != 0:
    ax.text(j, i, str(z), ha="center", va="center")

ax.set_title("Name Co-Occurrences")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the actual matrix I have is fairly large, so I would like to display the names both on the top and the bottom. I've tried to do so by using `twiny`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
names = ['Long Name ' + suffix for suffix in string.ascii_uppercase[:n]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n,n)),
                  columns=names, index=names)

fig = plt.figure()
botax = plt.gca()

im = botax.matshow(df, interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(im)

topax = botax.twiny()
for ax, ha, pos in zip([topax, botax], ["left", "right"], ["top", "bottom"]):
  ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n))
  ax.set_xticklabels(names)
  ax.set_yticks(np.arange(n))
  ax.set_yticklabels(names)
  ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position(pos)
  plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45,
           ha=ha, va="center", rotation_mode="anchor")

for (i,j), z in np.ndenumerate(df):
  if z != 0:
    botax.text(j, i, str(z), ha="center", va="center")

botax.set_title("Name Co-Occurrences")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately the top labels aren't aligned correctly and I don't know why: [image: Misaligned X tick labels]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to label both, bottom and top of an axes, there is no need for a twin axes. This may make this all a bit easier. You can instead just turn the bottom and top ticks and labels on, and then rotate and align them separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
names = ['Long Name ' + suffix for suffix in string.ascii_uppercase[:n]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n,n)),
                  columns=names, index=names)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

im = ax.matshow(df, interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(im)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n))
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(n))
ax.set_yticklabels(names)

# Set ticks on both sides of axes on
ax.tick_params(axis="x", bottom=True, top=True, labelbottom=True, labeltop=True)
# Rotate and align bottom ticklabels
plt.setp([tick.label1 for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()], rotation=45,
         ha="right", va="center", rotation_mode="anchor")
# Rotate and align top ticklabels
plt.setp([tick.label2 for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()], rotation=45,
         ha="left", va="center",rotation_mode="anchor")

ax.set_title("Name Co-Occurrences", pad=55)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very clean approach, thanks. Do you know of a way to calculate the title padding automatically?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258363/read-height-of-legend-in-python/55272871#55272871), just use the maximum of the heights of the labels, instead of the legend.

Comment: You shouldn't have to pad, so this is a bug of the title not taking into account the rotation of the ticks labels.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9498

Comment: The title not moving was a bug: thanks for pointing it out.  See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13741 for a fix...

Comment: How would you add different labels on top and bottom?

Comment: @Stefan Try Sheldore's answer for that, passing in different labels for top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to first set the aspect ratio of the upper x-axis to be the same as that of the lower x-axis. How to do this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030928/4932316). Then you can use `y=1.3` to lift the title a bit upward so that it does not overlap with the upper x-axis tick labels.

```
topax = botax.twiny()

aspect0 = botax.get_aspect()
if aspect0 == 'equal':
    aspect0 = 1.0
dy = np.abs(np.diff(botax.get_ylim()))
dx = np.abs(np.diff(botax.get_xlim()))

aspect = aspect0 / (float(dy) / dx)
topax.set_aspect(aspect)

for ax, ha, pos in zip([topax, botax], ["left", "right"], ["top", "bottom"]):
  ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n))
  .....
  .....

botax.set_title("Name Co-Occurrences", y=1.3)
```

[image]