# Ticks and Labels on Twin Axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

**How can I set the labels on the extra axes?**

The ticks and labels should be the same on all 4 axes. I'm doing something wrong... Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
plt.show()

# create reusable ticks and labels
ticks = [0,1/2,3.14159/4,3.14159/2,1]
labels = [r"$0$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$", r"$1$"]

# Version 1: twinx() + xaxis.set_ticks()
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
ax3.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
plt.show()

# Version 2: twinx() + set_xticklabels)()
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
ax1.set_xticks(ticks)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax1.set_yticks(ticks)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax2.set_xticks(ticks)
ax2.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax3.set_yticks(ticks)
ax3.set_yticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Confused: How come ax1 has both xaxis and yaxis, while ax2, ax3 do not appear to?

Comment: With `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`, axes 1 and 2 share the x-axis. That means calling `ax1.xaxis.set_ticks` makes `ax2.xaxis.set_ticks` redundant. You want to specify `ax2.yaxis`'s ticks and labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unintuitive solution based on [matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html):

> Create a new Axes with an **invisible x-axis** and an **independent y-axis**
> positioned opposite to the original one (i.e. at right).

This means ***unintuitively*** (at least for me) you have to switch x/y at the `.twin` call.

- *unintuitively* not concerning the general matplotlib twinx functionality, but concerning such a manual ticks and label assignment
- To highlight that a bit more I used `ax2_x` and `ax3_y` in the code.

**Disclaimer:** Not sure if that will break your plot intention when data is added.

- Probably at least you have to take special care with the data assignment to those twin axes - keeping that "axis switch" in mind.
- Also keep that axis switch" in mind when assigning different ticks and labels to the x/y axis.

But for now I think that's the plot you were looking for:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True


# create reusable ticks and labels
ticks = [0,1/2,3.14159/4,3.14159/2,1]
labels = [r"$0$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$", r"$1$"]



plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)


ax2_x = ax1.twiny()  # switch
ax3_y = ax1.twinx()  # switch

ax2_x.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels) 
ax3_y.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

Or switch the `x/yaxis.set_ticks` - with the same effect:

- On second thought, I assume that's the **preferred way to do it, especially when data comes into play**.

```
ax2_x = ax1.twinx()
ax3_y = ax1.twiny()
    
ax2_x.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)  # switch
ax3_y.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)  # switch
```

---

In case you don't intend to use the twin axis functionality (that means having different data with different scaling assigned to those axis) but **'only' want the ticks and labels on all 4 axis for better plot readability**:

Solution based on [answer of ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290400) with the same plot result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True


# create reusable ticks and labels
ticks = [0,1/2,3.14159/4,3.14159/2,1]
labels = [r"$0$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$", r"$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$", r"$1$"]


plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
ax1.tick_params(axis="x", bottom=True, top=True, labelbottom=True, labeltop=True)
ax1.tick_params(axis="y", left=True, right=True, labelleft=True, labelright=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`ax2 = ax1.twinx()` shares the x-axis with `ax1`.
`ax3 = ax1.twiny()` shares the y-axis with `ax1`.
As a result, the two lines where you set `ax2.xaxis` and `ax3.yaxis`'s ticks and ticklabels are redundant with the changes you already applied on `ax1`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False # My computer doesn't have LaTeX, don't mind me. 

# Create reusable ticks and labels.
ticks = [0, 1/2, 3.14159/4, 3.14159/2, 1]
labels = [r"$0$", r"$\frac{1}{2}$", r"$\frac{\pi}{4}$", r"$\frac{\pi}{2}$", r"$1$"]

# Set the ticks and ticklabels for each axis.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
for axis in (ax1.xaxis,
             ax1.yaxis,
             ax2.yaxis,
             ax3.xaxis):
    axis.set_ticks(ticks)
    axis.set_ticklabels(labels)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Notice that if I comment out the work on `ax2` and `ax3`, we get exactly what you have in your question:

```py
for axis in (ax1.xaxis, ax1.yaxis,
             # ax2.yaxis,
             # ax3.xaxis,
            ):
    axis.set_ticks(ticks)
    axis.set_ticklabels(labels)
```

[image]

Now let's ruin `ax1` via modifications on `ax2`, just to show that the bound between twins works well:

```py
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(range(10))
ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels(tuple("abcdefghij"))
```

[image]